# Issues adding datepicker to dynamically created fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Ok, so I'm trying to dynamically generate a form field, and then add a datepicker to but every time I add a new datepicker it removes all the previous datepickers on the form.

```
class morePayments {

    constructor() {
        this.state = 0;
    };

    changeState() {
        this.state = this.state + 1;
        if (this.state <= 5) {
            var dummy = '<fieldset class="form-group row">' +
                        '<label class="col-xs-2 text-right control-label">Amount:</label>' +
                        '<div class="col-xs-4"><input type="text" id="payment[]" name="payment[]"></div>' +
                        '<div class="col-xs-5">' +
                            '<div class="input-group">' +
                                '<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>' +
                                '<input type="text" id="paymentdate-' + 
                                this.state + '" name="paymentdate-' + this.state + '" />' +
                                '</div>' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</fieldset>'
            document.getElementById('modal-body-payment').innerHTML += dummy;
            $( "#paymentdate-" + this.state ).datepicker({
              dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
            });
        }
    };

};

state = new morePayments();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
document.getElementById('modal-body-payment').innerHTML += dummy;
```

When you rewrite innerHTML it means that DOM tree is completely rebuild which of course means that you lose all previously bound event handlers.

Instead append new content:

```
$('#modal-body-payment').append(dummy);
```

Comment: append just adds text though do would it be possible to just create a loop at the end of the function to readd all the datepickers?